# Creating 3 column Word footer from PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint, footer, multiple-columns

I am creating Word document from PowerPoint, copying slides in a table etc.
Then I make a footer like this :

```
Const wdSeekCurrentPageFooter = 10
Const wdFieldEmpty = -1
...
wrdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Column1" & " " & CStr(Date) & " " & "Page "
wrdApp.Selection.Fields.Add Range:=wrdApp.Selection.Range, _
Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
wrdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=" of "
wrdApp.Selection.Fields.Add Range:=wrdApp.Selection.Range, _
Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES  ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

So I get 3 info in footer, but I can make them appear nice using Tabs, I would like something like

- Manual add footer, built-in, Blank(Three Columns) or
- Footer, insert 3 texts, edit, insert alignment tabs

But I can't make any of these 2 solutions to work from PowerPoint VBA.

1. When looping through templates I can't see "Building Blocks.dotx"
2. This code breaks (named argument not found)

   ```
   wrdApp.Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab Alignment:=0,Relative:=0,Leader:=0
   ```

I need solution to work in Offices 2007 2010  and 2013. Any ideas how to make this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InsertAlignmentTab only has 2 parameters, Alignment and RelativeTo (not Relative)

For VBA to "see" the names of parameters, you need to make a
    reference (Tools->References...) to the Word object model. But since
    you are targetting multiple versions of Office, you are probably
    trying to avoid that, in which case, use positional parameter
    passing

```
wrdApp.Selection.Range.InsertAlignmentTab 0, 0
```

re. looping for Building Blocks, I would guess that you cannot guarantee that Building Blocks.dotx exists.